# When i have duplicate values of date and time i want to get the results with the earliest value

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, duplicates

Here is my table:

```
DateOfPerformance   DateOfPerformance4Sort    userfullname
19/06/2012          2012-06-19 13:38:36.630   T Tes
**19/06/2012        2012-06-19 17:59:18.933   Zazon Rotem
19/06/2012          2012-06-19 13:21:18.770   Zazon Rotem**
05/07/2012          2012-07-05 09:50:20.437   Hazani Efrat
05/06/2012          2012-06-05 17:19:23.670   Mark Oded
11/07/2012          2012-07-11 17:37:20.490   Aviv Test
19/06/2012          2012-06-19 13:36:33.583   Roys Ady
05/07/2012          2012-07-05 09:50:20.497   T Rose
```

As you can see I have two rows with the same `userfullname` only the difference is the `dateofperformance4sort`

What should I do to get the same results with the earliest performance date?

Comment: Hi it should be a simple sql 2008

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that users can have performances on different days . . .

```
create table your_table (
  DateOfPerformance date not null,
  DateOfPerformance4Sort datetime not null,
  userfullname varchar(20) not null
);
insert into your_table values
('2012-06-19', '2012-06-19 13:38:36.630', 'T Tes'),
('2012-06-19', '2012-06-19 17:59:18.933', 'Zazon Rotem'),  -- Two more performances
('2012-06-19', '2012-06-19 13:21:18.770', 'Zazon Rotem'),  -- down below.
('2012-07-05', '2012-07-05 09:50:20.437', 'Hazani Efrat'),
('2012-06-05', '2012-06-05 17:19:23.670', 'Mark Oded'),
('2012-07-11', '2012-07-11 17:37:20.490', 'Aviv Test'),
('2012-06-19', '2012-06-19 13:36:33.583', 'Roys Ady'),
('2012-07-05', '2012-07-05 09:50:20.497', 'T Rose'),
('2012-07-19', '2012-07-19 11:21:18.770', 'Zazon Rotem'),
('2012-07-19', '2012-07-19 23:21:18.770', 'Zazon Rotem');
```

. . . it's just a simple aggregate query.

```
select userfullname, DateOfPerformance, min(DateOfPerformance4Sort) DateOfPerformance4Sort
from your_table
group by userfullname, DateOfPerformance
order by userfullname, DateOfPerformance
```

It returns two rows form Zazon Rotem, because he had performances on two different dates.

```
Zazon Rotem 2012-06-19  June, 19 2012 13:21:18-0700
Zazon Rotem 2012-07-19  July, 19 2012 11:21:18-0700
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to solve this, to get one value per user, is to use row_number():

```
select t.DateOfperformance, DateOfPerformance4Sort, userfullname
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userfullname order by DateOfPerformance4Sort
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) a
where seqnum = 1
```

This assigns a sequential number to each record for each user in the subquery.  It then just chooses the first one.